Serverlogfile import via cronjob/Python script. How to import the logfile from the PREVIOUS day?
I import the server logfiles into Matomo via the following script in a cronjob:
 python /html/matomo3/misc/log-analytics/import_logs.py --url=https://matomo3.mydomain.com/ --idsite=3 --recorders=4 --enable-http-errors --enable-http-redirects --enable-static /logs/access.log
How can I import not /logs/access.log but the logfile of the previous day logs/archive/yyyy_mm_dd-access.log instead?
can i do this:
python import datetime  Previous_Date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1) /html/matomo3/misc/log-analytics/import_logs.py --url=https://matomo3.mydomain.com/ --idsite=3 --recorders=4 --enable-http-errors --enable-http-redirects --enable-static /logs/archive/Previous_Date-access.log

Hi, try to add something like that to your code:  date --date=yesterday +/logs/access_log_%Y-%m-%d.gz'
